# XSLT - previous nodes across ancestors, getting wrong count

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have some XML like the following:

```
<layout>
    <table>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <ref id="stock1" class="pile stock"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <ref id="cascade1" class="pile"/>
                            <ref id="cascade2" class="pile"/>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</layout>
```

I'm trying to get a count of how many cards have been used by the preceding `ref`s, because each `ref` points to another tag elsewhere in the document that has `card` children.

```
<xsl:variable name="curPos" select="position()"/>
<!-- Layout could change, not guaranteed previous ref is in same parent node as
     current ref, or at the same depth. -->
<xsl:variable name="prevRefID"
  select="/layout//*/ref[position() &lt; $curPos]/@id"/>
<xsl:variable name="numCardsPrevUsed"
  select="count(/cardHolder/*[@id = $prevRefID]/card)"/>
```

The problem is I'm not always getting correct previously-used-card counts.  When at `ref` 'stock1', it correctly says 0 cards have been used so far, but when it gets to `ref` 'cascade1', it still says 0 cards have been used even though `ref` 'stock1' uses 24 cards.  Then when it gets to `ref` 'cascade2', it suddenly says that 25 cards have been used, which is correct (24 in 'stock1' + 1 in 'cascade1').  Why is the number of previously used cards incorrect at `ref` 'cascade1'?

**Edit:** yikes, here's some sample XML:

```
<game name="Klondike">
  <layout>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <ref id="stock1" class="pile stock"/>
                <ref id="waste1" colspan="2" class="empty-pile"/>
                <ref id="foundation1" class="empty-pile"/>
                <ref id="foundation2" class="empty-pile"/>
                <ref id="foundation3" class="empty-pile"/>
                <ref id="foundation4" class="empty-pile"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <ref id="cascade1" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade2" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade3" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade4" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade5" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade6" class="pile"/>
                <ref id="cascade7" class="pile"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </layout>
  <state id="start">
    <foundation id="foundation1" />
    <foundation id="foundation2" />
    <foundation id="foundation3" />
    <foundation id="foundation4" />
    <cascade id="cascade1">
      <card suit="random" number="random" faceup="true"/>
    </cascade>
    <cascade id="cascade2">
      <card suit="random" number="random"/>
      <card suit="random" number="random" faceup="true"/>
    </cascade>
    ...other cascades...
    <waste id="waste1" />
    <stock id="stock1">
      <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
        <card suit="random" number="random"/>
    </stock>
  </state>
</game>
```

Comment: Very unclear question. There are no "cards" in the XML document. What do you mean by "cards"? Is this really the XML document you are talking about? Please, edit your question and improve.

Comment: Ok, @SO we are all 'genius', and we can infer the XML input from your XSLT code...but you could _at least_, show the template context.

Comment: If you write `/layout` and then `/cardHolder` it means that your XML document _is not_ well formed.

Comment: I added sample XML to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all depends by current template context where your code fragment is placed and the consequent incorrect use of `position()`. The above fragment works fine if you are iterating on `ref` nodes, **not if you are matching on them**.

For instance in this situation:

```
 <xsl:template match="//ref">
 <!-- your fragment -->
 </xsl:template>
```

your code will never work, because `postion()` **is not** obviously **progressive**. You should use something like:

```
    <xsl:variable name="curPos" 
                  select="count(../preceding-sibling::tr/ref 
                                | preceding-sibling::ref)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$curPos"/>
        <xsl:variable name="prevRefID"
            select="//layout//*/ref
                    [count(preceding-sibling::ref) &lt; $curPos]/@id"/>
```

or better, change the template context so that you can use `position()`.

Comment: You have updated your question, but you have neither commented my answer with a feedback nor shown more of your current used template.